# Is there a standard format for /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/topology/thread_siblings_list?

Tags: linux

Considering the following command.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/topology/thread_siblings_list
```

When I run this command on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04, I get the following output.

```
0,1
```

However, when I run it on a server running Debian 8, I get the following output.

```
0-1
```

**Is the standard format or set of standard formats for this pseudo-file documented somewhere?**

I searched in the Documentation directory under the kernel source and did not find a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an documented way but turbostat, an internal program and part of [linux-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600609/what-is-linux-tools-package-is-it-needed-for-average-desktop-user), expects the format to be:

A number, followed by any character as seperator, ..., the last number.

The current version is [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b272f732f888d4cf43c943a40c9aaa836f9b7431/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c#L1849).

```
/*
 * get_cpu_position_in_core(cpu)
 * return the position of the CPU among its HT siblings in the core
 * return -1 if the sibling is not in list
 */
int get_cpu_position_in_core(int cpu)
{
    char path[64];
    FILE *filep;
    int this_cpu;
    char character;
    int i;

    sprintf(path,
        "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu%d/topology/thread_siblings_list",
        cpu);
    filep = fopen(path, "r");
    if (filep == NULL) {
        perror(path);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < topo.num_threads_per_core; i++) {
        fscanf(filep, "%d", &this_cpu);
        if (this_cpu == cpu) {
            fclose(filep);
            return i;
        }

        /* Account for no separator after last thread*/
        if (i != (topo.num_threads_per_core - 1))
            fscanf(filep, "%c", &character);
    }

    fclose(filep);
    return -1;
}
```